# Flow direction CartoCSS

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

I'm working on a TileMill project essentially displaying freight routes. The original shapefile contains a origin city and a destination city (and a path between both cities). When I apply a `marker-type:arrow; /marker-placement:line;` code in CartoCSS, I just don't quite understand the logic of how arrow direction actually gets assigned in this case. Ideally obviously I would like the arrows to point in the origin city to destination city direction.

Comment: Each line has a 'direction', defined implicitly by the order of coordinates of the geometry. If the result is backwards, I suspect your geometry has been defined 'backwards'; that is, it was drawn destination→origin, rather than origin→destination.

Comment: I want to add arrows to my basemap, the arrows are hidden under roads, they are not appear on the roads and I don't know if they are in the right direction and for both of direction in the same road, how to make it? I use : ::decoration [zoom >= 16]{ marker-type:arrow; marker-placement:line; }

Comment: Please, don't post questions in the answer box. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94609)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
{
     line-join: round;
     line-width:3;
     line-color:blue; 
     ::decoration {
           marker-type:arrow;       
           marker-placement:vertex-last;
      }
}
```